# Take a message from the user and display it, But when i click the button the app stops

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app which takes a message from the user and displays the message in a new tab when a button(send) is pressed, but when I click the button the app stops without displaying the message

**main activity**

```
 package com.example.prakash.myfirst;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.Myfirst.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = "hi";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

**display message activity**

```
   package com.example.prakash.myfirst;

     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(message);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
  <Button
        android:text="@string/send_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        tools:text="@string/send_button"
        tools:hint="@string/send_button"
        android:onClick="sendMessage (MainActivity)"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_msg" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

android manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.prakash.myfirst">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

logcat

```
 04-21 06:01:54.454 6266-6266/com.example.prakash.myfirst 
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
 length
 >04-21 06:01:54.454 6266-6266/com.example.prakash.myfirst 
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
 length
 04-21 06:01:55.652 6266-6266/com.example.prakash.myfirst 
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
 length
 04-21 06:01:55.652 6266-6266/com.example.prakash.myfirst 
 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero 
 length
 04-21 06:01:59.147 6266-6266/com.example.prakash.myfirst E/AndroidRuntime: 
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main

  Process: com.example.prakash.myfirst, PID: 6266                                                                     
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sendMessage 
  (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick 
  attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton 
  with id 'button'
```

Comment: post logcat error

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: Make sure you add your activity in AndroidMainfest

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Check have you added your DisplayMessageActivity in Manifest

    <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"/>

Comment: @johny@mahrati aditya S S ,I have posted the Androidmainfest.xml

Comment: There is a message when the app crashes, it's called the logcat, please try to find it

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS i have posted AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have uploaded the logcat error message

Comment: Where did you learn how to set a click listener for a button? The `(MainActivity)` is not correct

Comment: You please remove (Mainactivity) inside () in XML. In activity you didn't use the edittext anywhere so remove that too also remove View Parameter . Then check simple click will work. sendMessage() will work.

Comment: Check the answer and lemme know

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong for setting an onClick listener.
android:onClick="sendMessage (MainActivity)"

I wouldn't even bother declaring onClick like that. Just set it from code in your activity.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               sendMessage(v)
            }
          });
```

You may also really enjoy [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for bindings instead of always having to use findById and be able to annotate listener functions

Comment: I am getting setOnClickListene() can not  be resolved.

Comment: @prakash you spelled listener wrong... Use the autocomplete of the IDE